# Duda sobre palabra virtual c++

Tags: c++, herencia

Estaba haciendo un programa para mis clases de programación, donde tratamos entre otras cosas herencia. Mi profesor al principio de curso nos dijo que si queríamos que la clase hija pudiera sobrescribir métodos de la clase padre. Teníamos que poner virtual delante del método en la clase padre. Pero hace unos días, nos dio un código que contenía un método que para mí necesitaba modificar en la clase hija. La cosa era que no tenía virtual delante, entonces me dije que no podría modificarla sí no había el virtual. Entonces la cosa fue que mi profesor dijo que la sobrescribiéramos igual. Como si existiera la palabra clave virutal delante del método. Entonces hice un código para comprobarlo.

```
#include <iostream>
class padre{
    public:
    int algo(){
        return 1;
    }
};
class Hijo : public padre{
     public:
    /*int algo(){
        return 2;
    }*/
};
int main() {
    Hijo a;
    
    std::cout << a.algo();

    return 0;
}
```

Con este código actual la salida del cout es 1 por la función del padre. Pero si quito el comentario de la clase hija, la salida es 2.
Entonces no entiendo el uso de virtual, ya que sin este consigo el mismo resultado que se me explicó de poder sobrescribir funciones de la clase padre. He buscado en internet pero me dicen que es para que la clase hija pueda sobrescribir, sin que la padre tenga que declarar el cuerpo del método.
Dado mi explicación de mi situación, vengo a preguntar la autentica utilización del la palabra "virtual" en c++ y para que sirve. Ya que veo que lo que me ha dicho el profe no es del todo cierto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La palabra clave `virtual` nos sirve para marcar funciones que queremos que se resuelvan dinámicamente. ¿Qué significa eso?

Primero veamos el comportamiento **sin** funciones virtuales:

```
#include <iostream>

#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct B { void f() { P; } };
struct D : public B { void f() { P; } };

int main()
{
    B b;
    D d;

    b.f();
    d.f();

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> void B::f()
> void D::f()
> ```

Pero si añadimos punteros:

```
B b;
D d;
b.f();
d.f();

B *pb = &b;
B *pd = &d;
pb->f();
pd->f();
```

La salida es:

> ```
> void B::f()
> void D::f()
> void B::f()
> void B::f()
> ```

La última llamada a función miembro se hace sobre una instancia de `D` **pero** la función llamada es la de `B` porque usamos un puntero a `B`.

Ahora veámoslo **con** funciones virtuales:

```
struct B { virtual void f() { P; } };
struct D : public B { void f() { P; } };

int main()
{
    B b;
    D d;
    B *pb = &b;
    B *pd = &d;

    b.f();
    d.f();

    pb->f();
    pd->f();

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora la salida es:

> ```
> virtual void B::f()
> virtual void D::f()
> virtual void B::f()
> virtual void D::f()
> ```

Lo primero que llama la atención es que `D::f` se ha vuelto virtual pese a que no la hemos marcado como tal, eso es porque la *virtualidad* es [transitiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaci%C3%B3n_transitiva) y si estamos sobrescribiendo una función virtual, la función que sobrescribe será virtual impícitamente.

Lo segundo que llama la atención es que la última llamada a función miembro se hace ahora sobre la instancia `D` (como esperábamos), esto es porque la función derivada ha sobrescrito la función homónima virtual de la clase base.

Es decir: la información estática que tenemos es que el puntero que manejamos es a la base (`B *`); pero la función escogida para ejecutarse se decide dinámicamente.